# Remove the word "item" from cleveref link upon enumerate item

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, cleveref

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Sum \label{sum}
\item VAT \label{vat}
\item Total $=(\cref{sum}) + (\cref{vat})$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How to change the link format from "item 1" to "1". So I had "Total = (1) + (2)"?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `\ref`?

Comment: @Dan No, I used crefs accidentally by copying an example from the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\labelcref` instead of `\cref`, or you could run `\crefformat{enumi}{...}` to perform a low-level reset of how `\cref` outputs cross-references to single instances of items (pun intended...) of type `enumi`. If you use the second option, you can instruct LaTeX to surround the item number with left and right parentheses automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
%\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Strategy A: Use \verb+\labelcref+ instead of \verb+\cref+
\begin{enumerate}
\item Sum \label{sum1}
\item VAT \label{vat1}
\item $\text{Total}=(\labelcref{sum1}) + (\labelcref{vat1})$
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip
\noindent
Strategy B: Run \verb+\crefformat{enumi}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3}+
\crefformat{enumi}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Sum \label{sum2}
\item VAT \label{vat2}
\item $\text{Total}=\cref{sum2} + \cref{vat2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual `\ref` command doesn't try to be clever and just prints the number. In addition, you can customize the `\cref` references to enumerate items by using `\crefname{enumi}{}{}`. This uses an empty 'name' for the top-level enumerate counter. The `enumerate` environment uses counters `enumi`, `enumii`, etc. for the different levels. You can localize this to the `enumerate` environment by putting it inside the environment:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\crefname{enumi}{}{}
\item Sum \label{sum}
\item VAT \label{vat}
\item Total $=(\cref{sum}) + (\cref{vat})$
\end{enumerate}
```